# Diagonally dominant matrix — geometric interpretation

Tags: linear-algebra, intuition

I like to have a visual interpretation of mathematical concepts. This is simple for many important kinds of matrices: orthogonal matrices are rotations, diagonal matrices scale along the natural basis, symmetric matrices scale at an angle, etc. Is there a neat visual way of thinking about diagonally dominant matrices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A diagonally dominant matrix $M$ can be decomposed into $D(I+N)$, where $D$ consists of the diagonal entries of $M$, $I$ is the identity matrix, and $N$ is a hollow matrix, in which the sum of absolute values of entries in each row is no greater than 1.

By Gershgorin's Circle Theorem, the eigenvalues of $N$ are all between -1 and 1, so $\|Nv\|\leq\|v\|$.

Thus, what a diagonally dominant matrix does is take a vector, add to it a shorter one, and then scale the result along the natural basis.

This is a "necessary, but not sufficient" explanation, as not any matrix with eigenvalues between -1 and 1 looks like $N$.

Answer (score 0):

Diagonally dominant matrices can be viewed as a perturbation of diagonal matrices. Visually, think of a matrix that scales more than it shears.

Comment: The meaning of "more" is key here, then. If I decompose the matrix into the diagonal matrix and "noise," the noise matrix will be the original with each row divided by the corresponding diagonal entry. The definition tells us that the absolute values of each row of this noise matrix sum up to no more than 2. I'm not sure what that implies.